# Find the measurement of......

Tags: circles

Find the measurement of unknown angle in the given circle with centre at $O$.
[image]

My Attempt 
$1$. $\angle QRS=\angle PQR$

$2$. $\angle PQR=\angle PMR$.

I am struck here. Please help me with this problem..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\angle PMQ = 90^{\circ}$ as $PQ$ is the diameter of the circle. Now additionally we have that $\angle QMS = \angle PMR$. So using this we have:

$$\angle PMR = \frac{90^{\circ} - 60^{\circ}}{2} = 15^{\circ}$$

Comment: How is $\angle QMS=\angle PMR$?

Comment: $PQ \parallel RS$, so $PQRS$ is a inscribed trapezium, hence ${QS} = {PR}$, so the angles subtended by these arcs are same.

Comment: Is the inscribed tapezium isosceles?

Comment: @user335710 Yeah, it's a well-known fact.